# Where can I get the grid representation for a projection on meters?

Tags: coordinate-system

In PostGIS I have the following projection:

```
aut_srid = 21781    

text = "PROJCS["CH1903 / LV03",GEOGCS["CH1903",DATUM["CH1903",
SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
TOWGS84[674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6149"]],     
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4149"]],PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",46.95240555555556],
PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",7.439583333333333],
PARAMETER["azimuth",90],PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle",90],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",600000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",200000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Y",EAST],AXIS["X",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","21781"]]"
```

I found this picture in the PDF at the end of the [**link**](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/knowledge-facts/surveying-geodesy/reference-systems/map-projections.html#ui-tab-764) but I need a map file with the grid representation, something in shapefile, tab or similar.

[image]

Comment: do you want to recreate these maps (i.e. how the two projections differ in metres) or do you want a grid in epsg;21781 ?

Comment: @IanTurton I need the grid

Comment: Not 100% sure if this would work for you, but you can create your own grid based on the projection of the file: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfXmS2H06h8

Comment: @RachelRotz I see in the video they use some degrees, but dont see they use a projection file? How I set the parameters with my projection?